# Show divs when links are hovered - to include drop content

Tags: jquery, hover

I have a slightly tricky one here I hope the community can help me with... I'll try and explain what I want as clearly and simply as possible...

I have a menu of links in divs
I am using dropcontent.js to show a div (and load project content into it) when the link in a div is clicked. I have this working fine.

Now I want to add a hover effect to the link (and its containing div) so that another div shows when the link is hovered on. This div will contain intro text to the project. This div should stay visible when either the link in the div is hovered on, or this intro div itself is hovered on. Clicking anywhere on this intro div should also show the main div and load the project conent into it. Once the main project div has loaded, the intro div should remain visible until the main project div is hidden (by clicking on another project)

So, my html looks like this

```
<div class="menu_body">

<div class="work">
  <h3><a href="project1.html">Project 1</a></h3>
  <div class="projectIntro">
    <p>This is some intro text for project 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pictures"></div>
</div>

<div class="work">
  <h3><a href="project2.html">Project 2</a></h3>
  <div class="projectIntro">
    <p>This is some other intro text for project 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class=“pictures”></div>
</div>

</div><!--end menu_body -->
```

Logic...

• When the project 1 h3 link (and its containing div) is hovered on, the .projectIntro div for project 1 shows

• When the .projectIntro div for project 1 is hovered on, it should remain showing

• If another link in the list is hovered, it’s intro div will show and the previous intro div will hide

• If project 1 h3 link, or its intro div is clicked the div containing the main project content (.pictures) should show and load the content

• If main project div is visible, it’s intro div is also always visible

• A main project div is hidden by clicking for a second time on it’s link, or clicking on the link for another project (already working)

I hope that’s clear! If not please let me know…

So the problem I am having is as follows:

The main issue I am having is with the hovers this is the code I currently have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //when user hovers over .work the projectIntro is shown
    $(".projectIntro").hide();
    $(".work").hover(

    function() {
        $(".projectIntro").show("fast");
    }, function() {
        $(".projectIntro").mouseout.hide("slow");
    });


    $('.projectIntro').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function(event) {
        switch (event.type) {
        case 'mouseenter':
            // when user enters the div
            $(".projectIntro").show("fast");
            break;
        case 'mouseleave':
            // leaves
            $(".projectIntro").hide("slow");
            break;
        }
    });
});
```

I sourced this code from a related search I did on here...

The first main issue I have is that this code was for a single link, not a list of links - so when I hover over a link, the projectIntro for all links is showing. I am sure I should be using children so that only the relevant project intro shows but I am a bit confused as to how to change the code so it works like that.

Second, it seems to be triggering the animations multiple times on hover so I need a .stop somewhere - just not sure where!

Third, the projectIntro should always show when the main project pictures div is loaded but not quite sure how to do that either

I think that’s it - sorry this is fairly long winded but trying to be as clear as possible

you can see where I am with this here:

http://www.spiritlevel.co.uk/hovertest/hovertest.html

thanks in advance for any help!

UPDATE:

Thanks to KoolKabin this is now very nearly sorted

http://www.spiritlevel.co.uk/hovertest/hovertest4.html

... my only issue now is how to keep .projectIntro visible if .pictures is visible (regardless of any hover)

KoolKabin said "Put pictures inside .projectIntro and style project titles with another class inside.."

I have tried putting the .pictures div inside the .projectIntro div but this stops .pictures  showing when it's link is clicked

http://www.spiritlevel.co.uk/hovertest/hovertest5.html

and I'm not sure what he meant by "style project titles with another class inside"

As it's now past 11pm in Nepal I think KoolKabin may be taking a well deserved rest so if anyone else could help me out with this last bit it would be appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: You missing out to tell the child element in jquery...

Comment: Yes I know (I mentioned that above) - the problem is I'm not sure how to do that - my tests so far have failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try out referring to direct child only by using .children ....

```
$(".work").hover(

    function() {
        $(this).children(".projectIntro").show("fast");
    }, function() {
        $(this).children(".projectIntro").mouseout.hide("slow");
    })
```

A Complete workout for your code:

```
$(".work").hover(
    function() {
    $(this).children(".projectIntro").show("fast");
  }, function(){
    $(this).children(".projectIntro").hide("slow");
  });


  $('.projectIntroX').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function(event) {
    switch(event.type) {
        case 'mouseenter':
           // when user enters the div
           //$(this).show("fast");
        break;
        case 'mouseleave':
          // leaves
          //$(this).hide("slow");
        break;
    }
});
```

And working example on: 
http://www.outsourcingnepal.com/sample-code/jqueryCheck.htm

Comment: Thanks - I appreciate your help. Now only the relevant projectIntro div triggers. BUT there are 2 issues. First the projectIntro div is not hiding when the link that triggered it is rolled off. and second, when the projectIntro div for project 1 is hovered on, it shows the projectIntro div for project 2 - http://www.spiritlevel.co.uk/hovertest/hovertest2.html - I tried adding the $(this).children to the second part of the code which controls the hover on the projectIntro div, but that seems to stop either projectIntro div from hiding again http://www.spiritlevel.co.uk/hovertest/hovertest3.html

Comment: Sorry missed your edit originally - that's brilliant! thank you so much! I think the only issue now is that I would like the projectIntro div to remain visible whenever the main project div (.pictures) is visible - currently is hides when the cursor is not hovering on either the link, the .projevtintro div or the pictures div - http://www.spiritlevel.co.uk/hovertest/hovertest4.html

Comment: Also, would you mind explaining what you did there with .projectIntroX? many thanks

Comment: .ProjectIntroX is just to show that you can remove that code... :P

Comment: Ah OK thanks - your help is much appreciated. I would vote your answer up if I could but I don't have enough reputation to do it unfortunately. Can you give me some points as to how I keep .projectIntro visible if .pictures is visible? thanks again!

Comment: you can choose the answer as the correct one if it helped. And about keeping projectIntro visible use simple trick. Put pictures inside .projectIntro and style project titles with another class inside..

Comment: Thanks - I think I understand what you're getting at by putting .pictures div inside .projectIntro, but when I do that my main project divs no longer load (probably a problem with drop content3.js) ...and not quite sure what you mean by style project titles with another class inside - sorry if I'm being dumb... Here is a version with .pictures inside .projectIntro - http://www.spiritlevel.co.uk/hovertest/hovertest5.html

Comment: @roxon - do you mean I should mark the question as answered? The reason I have not done so yet is because part of my orignal question was "the projectIntro should always show when the main project pictures div is loaded" and that part is not solved yet. KoolKabin has been a great help and I am 90% there but if I mark the question as answered then people will think it is completely solved when it is not...

Comment: @Spirit : cool than. It was just to inform a new user. Happy coding!